# Does the HERE Isoline Routing API have a max time limit?

Tags: here-api

Does anyone know whether the HERE Isoline Routing API has a limit on how many hours you can plug in?

For example, 6 hours works perfectly fine and has a service area output:

```
    'https://isoline.router.hereapi.com/v8/isolines?transportMode=car&origin=52.51578,13.37749&range[type]=distance&range[values]=21600&routingMode=fast'
```

However, I get a error if I try and do 12 hours

```
    'https://isoline.router.hereapi.com/v8/isolines?transportMode=car&origin=52.51578,13.37749&range[type]=distance&range[values]=43200&routingMode=fast'
```

In .parse_response(i, out$responses()[[i]]) :
https://isoline.router.hereapi.com/v8/isolines: Request 'id = 1' failed.
Status 400; Bad Request; Bad request syntax or unsupported method.

Is there a max time you can use on the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum value for the time is 9 hours.